# MongoDB shell: How to remove specific elements in all the collections inside a DB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-shell

I would like to remove, in all collections, all coincidences with a regex expression.

I need this, because a JSON parser failed in my app at a certain point today, and now the database is corrupted.

I could do it by hand, but I have  over 100+ collections, and manually entering in mongo shell
`db["X"].remove({ "DateTime": { $regex : "2015-11-16" } })` for each collection would take quite a few time.

Do you know any way to perform this automatically inside mongo shell? I always access this database via package `RMongo` in R, and I could do it via `dbRemoveQuery(rmongo.object, collection, query)` but I was wondering if it could be done inside mongo shell, maybe a little quicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
use yourDbName

// Get the names of all collections in the database.
var names = db.getCollectionNames();

// Iterate over every collection name.
for(i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {

    // Only issue the query if the collection is not a system collection.
    if(!names[i].startsWith("system.")) {

        // Issue the query against the collection with the name `names[i]`.
        db[names[i]].remove({ "DateTime": { $regex : "2015-11-16" } });
    }
}
```

Please note that I am excluding [**system collections**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/system-collections/) from the list.

Answer (score 2):

In mongo shell:

```js
 db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(name) {
     db[name].remove({ "DateTime": { $regex : "2015-11-16" } });
 })
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but (doesn't know why), didn't perform it well.

Comment: @Sergio I have fixed this answer. Now it will work as well.

Comment: Thanks, but it was no problem of the missing `)`, I put it after it failed, but after that, I examined the collections and the documents were still there.

Comment: @Sergio the closing `)` was not the only thing I have fixed ;-) I also added the `name` argument to the callback function and used it like this: `db[name]`.

Answer (score 1):

Well `.startsWith()` is a new technology, part of the ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) standard so it may not work in Mongo Shell.

You will need to use the [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to discard system collections

```
var collections = db.getCollectionNames().filter(function(collection) {
    return collection.indexOf('system.') !== -1;
};
```

Then remove the documents that match you criteria here where `"DateTime": "2015-11-16"`

```
for(var index=0; index < collections.length; index++) {
    db[collections[index]].remove( { 'DateTime': /2015-11-16/ } )
}
```